How can Rutherford conclude that most of the atom's mass (as opposed to charge) was concentrated in a central nucleus?
I don't understand how Rutherford can conclude from his scattering experiments that the nucleus's mass is concentrated in the center. I can see why the experiments suggest that the charge is concentrated at the center, and can also see why they suggest that the atom's mass is much bigger than the alpha particle's mass, but I don't see how the logic goes for the mass distribution.
To illustrate, why can't the nucleus be a hollow sphere with most of the mass in (uncharged) surface of the sphere and a small point charge in the center? The alpha particle should still be able to scatter off such a construct, since the electric force dominates the interaction and the surface of the sphere could be permeable (c.f. the Thomson model, where the atom is permeable).
I am looking for an explanation as to why we can deduce the mass distribution from the Rutherford scattering experiments.
Related: How did Rutherford conclude that most of the mass distribution was concentrated in a central nucleus? and How did Rutherford conclude that most of the mass (as well as the positive charge) was concentrated in the nucleus? However, none of the answers to either question address this in detail.

The first answer in the first related question does address this. Some alpha particles are deflected almost $180^\circ$, which requires most mass, not just positive charge, to be in the centre. I also recommend you Ctrl+F "mass" here; it's covered several times.

@J.G. How so? I've read that answer several times and I don't see how you need most mass to be in the center. It only says (second last paragraph) that the target has greater mass than the incident particle.

Hmm, a good point. I guess he just assumed that the charge density was proportional to the mass density ...

But you can quantify how much greater. It works out at basically the full atomic mass.

@J.G. yes, but if the mass distribution was rigid there would be no way to tell. The conclusion that most mass is at the centre relies on the assumption that whatever is at the centre can move independently of the rest of the atom. Obviously this is true since you can scatter the nucleus and the electrons separately, but that was an assumption that Rutherford had to make.

@J.G. Yeah you can work out the atom's mass, but how do you work out the mass distribution (here meaning how the mass is spread out across the atom)?

It looks like the answer is that he didn't. He only constrained the charge distribution. Mass distribution is not constrained.
Source

In comparing the theory outlined in this paper with the experimental results, it has been supposed that the atom consists of a central charge supposed concentrated at a point, and that the large single deflexions of the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ particles are mainly due to their passage through the strong central field.

This shows he's only constraining the charge distribution.
He is aware he is dealing with an atom that's significantly more massive than alpha particles:

In cases where the mass of the deflecting atom (for example, hydrogen, helium, lithium) is not very different from that of the $\alpha$ particle, the general theory of single scattering will require modification, for it is necessary to take into account the movements of the atom itself (see section 4).

But at no point does he attempt to model how the mass is distributed in the atom. He models only the concentrated central charge, and acknowledges that it is possible that the charge moves, but it (and the stability of the atom) is not his concern right now:

The question of the stability of the atom proposed need not be considered at this stage, for this will obviously depend upon the minute structure of the atom, and on the motion of the constituent charged parts.


There are probably other models which could account for the scattering pattern that Rutherford observed - especially if the models allow a separation of charge and mass - but Rutherford chose the simplest possible model that could explain his observations. In this he was applying the principle of Occam's razor:

The simplest explanation is usually the correct one

which has also been paraphrased as

When you hear hoofbeats, think of horses not zebras


Did Rutherford have enough information to confidently apply Occam's Razor, though? Like, the "simplest" explanation (mass distribution is the same as charge distribution) is also wrong - since neutrons and protons are not evenly distributed in nuclei. Neither is the assumption that he mass/charge distribution is spherically symmetric safe - since some molecules like H20 are clearly not spherically symmetric.


To illustrate, why can't the nucleus be a hollow sphere with most of the mass in (uncharged) surface of the sphere and a small point charge in the center? The alpha particle should still be able to scatter off such a construct, since the electric force dominates the interaction and the surface of the sphere could be permeable (c.f. the Thomson model, where the atom is permeable).

How can the mass be disembodied from the point charge? If so, what holds the mass to the charge? Why would the parts of the hollow sphere not fly apart from each other, especially when bombarded with alpha particles?
The permeable bits of a Thomson model atom get crashed and fly apart when high energy particles attack them. Permeability is just a problem when you think hard about this issue.

Why can't the mass be disembodied from the point charge? We can have most of the nucleus made of uncharged matter, while the point charge be carried by a nearly-massless particle. Like, to use modern terminology that Rutherford would not have, put a positron at the center of the atom and surround it with neutrons (which don't have to be spherically symmetrically arranged around the positron).

It is not that it cannot be disembodied by a bit, but that you would have to specify the mechanism for binding the disembodied mass with the charges. Knowing what we now know, we know that there is no inherent identity of neutrons and protons in a nucleus; they are continually exchanging virtual pions and thus exchanging identities, spreading out the charge to be uniformly distributed throughout the nucleus, mostly, with minor deviations from this uniform approximation. There is no mechanism for a complicated disembodiment.

But then we're applying modern physics to Rutherford, no? During Rutherford's era the state-of-the-art was the plum pudding model, which has no mechanism for how the electrons don't annihilate with the surrounding positive charge either. In fact Rutherford's model also has a "complicated disembodiment" since the electrons are separated from the nucleus.

Absent Millikan's oil drop experiment that determined the electron mass was so small, does Rutherford's scattering experiments show that the electron mass must be much smaller than the nucleus mass? If so, how? If not, then it seems the mass distribution is not constrained?

I am very much aware that you are trying to be historically accurate. But Rutherford had good reasons: Because Coulomb force law is so much stronger than Newtonian gravitational law, people had to have expected that there is charge neutrality in the atomic models. This, in turn, implies that the charges of nuclei are (small) integer multiples of the charge of an electron. Then, the JJ Thompson experiment measuring $\frac qm$ ratio can be used to show that proton, alpha, and other nuclei are a lot more massive than the electrons, even without Millikan's oil drop experiment.

That still doesn't exclude the possibility of neutral matter that make up most of the atom's mass in the nucleus, does it? (Like if protons were actually positrons in the nucleus and neutrons made up most of the mass.) There'd also be no constraint on where the "neutrons" can be in the nucleus, as well.

Look, it does not exclude the possibility, but you absolutely have to have a mechanism for holding the neutrons to the positrons, which you have not considered. These must be quite difficult bonds; it will have the similar kind of paradoxical behaviour as the æther: extremely tightly bonding, yet almost free for particles to just pass through them, such that these paradoxical behaviour is itself grounds for rejection of their existence. It is just extremely unnatural, and you are blatantly running into gandalf's answer.

That mechanism could just be yet-to-be-discovered new physics. Rutherford was apparently ready to accept a violation of classical electromagnetic theory (in which accelerating charges radiate); if one is ready to suspend belief in that, then one ought also be ready to accept extremely unnatural models of the atom.
